# Linguistic related question: 한국어 어절

Tags: particle, korean-to-english

I am majoring in Korean language and now stuck with the word **한국어 어절**.

While searching I found that 어절 is a combination of word and particle(조사) but so far it is not very clear.

Could anyone help to explain and give me some examples? or what is the equivalent English word?

I will be really thankful

Comment: `어절 is a combination of word and particle (조사)` are you sure? See https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%96%B4%EC%A0%88

Comment: oh I just searched about that word in Korean so I think I was confused about the definition. Thank you for your help for the link :)

Comment: There is no linguistic definition. Roughly, a 어절 is just a sequence of characters between two spaces. The governmental orthographic code defines rules for space insertion, though most native speakers don't really care all the details. See these for the code.  [1](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000073&mn_id=30) [2](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000074&mn_id=30) [3](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000075&mn_id=30) [4](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000076&mn_id=30)

Comment: wow thats good information! thank you so much for your kindly explanation! I have some ideas now about that!:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Almost case, 어절 is coincided to **spacing words** in a sentence.

For instance, the following sentence 아버지가 방에 들어 가신다 - a
(Father enter the room) has four 어절.

(2) In above sentence, if we do wrong spacing words, then we may
have 아버지 가방에 들어 가신다 - b

Note that this sentence is wrong, because we need a postpositional
word 는 or 가 after 아버지.

That is, 아버지는 가방에 들어 가신다 or 아버지가 가방에 들어 가신다
(Father enter the bag) - c

Even though b is wrong sentence, b is heard like c. That is, spacing
words is important.

(3) Another example : Korean did not admit spacing words, but
nowadays we do.

As like b, we can **catch different meaning** :

서울시 체육회 Seoul city exercise

서울 시체 육회 Seoul corpse a dish of minced beef

Comment: Hello HK Lee Ssi, thank you so much for your clear explanation!  I can understand your great examples. Therefore, if we talk about 한국어 어절 처리 it means we are going to learn about the meaning of the sentence that related to spacing ?